# Reshape dataframe to have the same index as another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, reindex

I have two dataframes:

```
dayData


        power_comparison      final_average_delta_power calculated_power
1                    0.0               0.0                  0       
2                    0.0               0.0                  0           
3                    0.0               0.0                  0           
4                    0.0               0.0                  0       
5                    0.0               0.0                  0           
7                    0.0               0.0                  0
```

and

```
historicPower

   power
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3   -1.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
7    0.0
```

I'm trying to reindex the `historicPower` dataframe to have the same shape as the `dayData` dataframe (so in this example it would looks like):

```
   power

1    0.0
2    0.0
3   -1.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
7    0.0
```

The dataframes in reality will be alot larger with different shapes.

Comment: Is index contain duplicates? If not, use `historicPower = historicPower.reindex(dayData.index)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if `index` has no duplicates:

```
historicPower = historicPower.reindex(dayData.index) 
print (historicPower)
   power
1    0.0
2    0.0
3   -1.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
7    0.0
```